# coefficients in glm vs. coefficients in loglm

Tags: r, statistics, glm

I fit a 3 dimensional contingency table (not provided here but I can if it can help) with a loglinear model, both with loglm and with glm.
The two results I get in terms of coefficients are:

```
> coefficients(nodnox_loglm_model)
$`(Intercept)`
[1] 10.18939

$w
       0.05         0.1        0.15         0.2        0.25         0.3        0.35         0.4        0.45 
-1.04596513 -0.41193617 -0.08840858  0.06407334 -0.06862606  0.02999039  0.17084795  0.45838071  0.35307375 
        0.5 
 0.53856982 

$s
          2           3           4           5 
 0.36697307  0.15164360 -0.48264571 -0.03597096
```

and

```
> coefficients(nodnox_glm_model)
(Intercept)          s3          s4          s5        w0.1       w0.15        w0.2       w0.25        w0.3 
  9.5104005  -0.2153295  -0.8496188  -0.4029440   0.6340290   0.9575566   1.1100385   0.9773391   1.0759555 
      w0.35        w0.4       w0.45        w0.5 
  1.2168131   1.5043458   1.3990389   1.5845350
```

I know that these two methods have different numerical procedure - I don't care about that - all I want to know is how can I relate the glm coefficients to the loglm coefficients?

All I found on the internet and the documentation I searched before coming to stackoverflow is this note:

> The glm coefficient table works just like the summary for ANOVA
>   produced by lm: the level alphabetically first (s2,w0.5) is used as an
>   intercept, and all subsequent levels are tested against the first
>   (thus the remaining coefficients are differences from the mean, not
>   means themselves).

To me, though, this is not enough to understand how to get the coefficients from the glm output in the form of loglm. 
Now, your question might be: "why not use loglm directly?" 
Loglm would not work in my case, (which is not the one I am comparing here, but it has a 5 dimensional table with some zeros. So if I use loglm on the original table, it gives me all the coefficients as NaNs). So I am stuck with glm and I really want to get the coefficients as in loglm.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have a two-way cross table with 10 levels of factor `w` and 5 levels of factor `s` with no interactions in the model. With `glm()`, the default coding scheme for categorical variables is [treatment coding](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm) where the first group in a factor is the reference level, and the respective parameter of each remaining group is its difference to this reference. The `(Intercept)` estimate is for the cell with all groups = reference level for their factor.

With `loglm()`, the parameters are for deviation coding, meaning that each group gets its own parameter, and the parameters for one factor sum to zero. `(Intercept)` is the grand mean that gets added to all group effects.

In your example, you could tell `glm()` to use deviation coding to get the same parameter estimates as with `loglm()` (see below for an example), or you convert the parameter estimates from treatment coding as follows:

- `w` = 0.05 and `s` = 2 is the reference cell:  `glm()` 9.5104005 = `loglm()` 10.18939 + -1.04596513 + 0.36697307
- `w` = 0.1 and `s` = 2 is reference level for `s` but needs the difference from `w` = 0.1 to the reference `w` = 0.05: `glm()` 9.5104005 + 0.6340290 = `loglm()` 10.18939 + -0.41193617 + 0.36697307
- `w` = 0.1 and `s` = 3 but needs the difference from `w` = 0.1 to the reference `w` = 0.05 and the difference from `s` = 3 to the reference `s` = 2: `glm()` 9.5104005 + 0.6340290 + -0.2153295 = `loglm()` 10.18939 + -0.41193617 + 0.15164360, and so on

Example with `glm()` using deviation coding (`UCBAdmissions` is a cross-table with absolute frequencies built into base R):

```
> library(MASS)                                # for loglm()
> llmFit <- loglm(~ Admit + Gender + Dept, data=UCBAdmissions)
> coef(llmFit)
$`(Intercept)`
[1] 5.177567

$Admit
  Admitted   Rejected 
-0.2283697  0.2283697 

$Gender
      Male     Female 
 0.1914342 -0.1914342 

$Dept
          A           B           C           D           E           F 
 0.23047857 -0.23631478  0.21427076  0.06663476 -0.23802565 -0.03704367 

> UCBdf <- as.data.frame(UCBAdmissions)  # convert to data frame for glm()
> glmFit <- glm(Freq ~ Admit + Gender + Dept, family=poisson(link="log"),
+               contrasts=list(Admit=contr.sum, Gender=contr.sum, Dept=contr.sum),
+               data=UCBdf)
> coef(glmFit)
(Intercept)      Admit1     Gender1       Dept1       Dept2       Dept3       Dept4 
 5.17756677 -0.22836970  0.19143420  0.23047857 -0.23631478  0.21427076  0.06663476 
      Dept5 
-0.23802565
```

Note that `glm()` does not list those parameter estimates that are fully determined (aliased) through the sum-to-zero constraint for the parameters for one factor.

Comment: how can I get the parameters estimates that are fully determined by the `sum-to-zero` constraints? i.e., if I get it right, the estimates for the reference category?

Comment: @maycca Not pretty (coefficient names are missing), but this works:   
`ce  <- coef(glmFit)[-1];  
cen <- gsub("(.+)[[:digit:]]+$", "\\1", names(ce));  
tapply(ce, cen, function(x) { c(x, -sum(x)) })`  
This is similar to `coef(llmFit)` from above, but can be generalized for the confidence intervals.